# Concatenate two columns in Excel VB Macro to column in second spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to concatenate two columns in People.xls `Range("A2: A100")` and `("B2:B100")` to Places.xls `Range ("A2: A100")` using a VB Macro. I've tried recording a macro and copying and pasting the values from an additional column in `C3: C100` which contained the concatenate formula `=CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2). But this doesn't see to work very well, and isn't very practical. Is there any way it can be done using VB in the macro itself? I've been playing around but I'm having no luck

Comment: I'd like very much to see the code you play with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Range("C1:C100")
    .Formula = "=Sheet2!A1&"" ""&Sheet3!B1"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: How does this select which columns to copy and concatenate?

Comment: the formula provides this: `RC[-2]` stands for same row, two columns to the left. thus, if entered in C1, it translates in A1 notation to `A1&" "&B1`

Comment: Ah ok, if the two columns are on a different spreadsheet, is it a simple case of using:
`Windows("Sheet2.xls").Activate`
before
`FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&"" ""&RC[-1]"`

Comment: `=Sheet2!RC[-2]&" "&Sheet3!RC[-1]` will give you A1 on sheet2 and B1 on sheet3

Comment: great. I updated the answer to an easier version - should have done this from the start.